# Регулярные выражения в C++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, g++, парсер, c++, linux

Здравствуйте! Возникла необходимость в написании парсера на C++.
На входе имеем два файла, в одном лежат входные данные (которые мы и будем проверять), а во втором - список регулярных выражений, по которым производится поиск.
На данный момент я вытащил из файла регулярки в массив типа string. В цикле перебираются строки, каждая из которых должна сравниваться с каждой регуляркой. Какие функции используются для поиска по регуляркам.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А какие регулярки? Они разные бывают...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в линуксе в g++ регулярные выражения сделаны немного "неполностью". Но есть буст, где это все есть и сделано достаточно хорошо. На хабре есть [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64226/) на эту тему.

Но если честно, то похоже Вы переизобретаете то, что уже есть в линуксе - grep. С помощью параметра `-f` можно задать файл с образцами (регулярными выражениями).

Comment: Спасибо, но возникла проблема с подключением буста к проекту <br>(/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex
collect2: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1)
<br>Компилирую: g++ main.cpp -o Main -lboost_regex

Comment: @Indev установить хедеры библиотеки в debian это 

    aptitude install libboost-regex-dev

Comment: @Indev, а попробуйте обычные regcomp/regexec. Кроме libc ничего не требуют. Известно, что работают.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо за помощь и потраченное время!